Find the size of the $CP$ segment. in the triangle below
In a triangle $ABC$ ($AB = BC$), the internal bisector $AD$ is drawn, then the bisector of angle $ADC$ intersects the base $AC$ at point $M$, the extension of the bisector of angle $ADB$ in the opposite direction intersects the extension of the base at point $P$.
Calculate the size of the $CP$ segment.
If: $CD = 4m$ and $MP = 14m$
(Answer:$11m$)
I made the drawing and tried
$\angle ADM \cong \angle MDC = \alpha$
$\angle BN \cong \angle NDA =  \theta$
$2\alpha + 2\theta = 180^o  \implies \alpha +\theta = 90^o $
$\therefore \angle NDM \cong \angle MDP = 90^o $
$\frac{AD}{AN} = \frac{4}{CM}$
$\frac{DB}{BN} = \frac{AD}{AN}$
$\triangle PDM: PD^2+DM^2 = (14)^2$
How do I finish?


As in my other answer, let
$$\measuredangle DAC = \beta \;\to\; \measuredangle DCA = 2\beta \;\to\; \measuredangle CDM = 90^{\circ} - \frac{3\beta}{2} \;\to\; \measuredangle DMC = 90^{\circ} - \frac{\beta}{2}$$
As you've determined, $\measuredangle PDM = 90^{\circ}$, so $\measuredangle MPD = \frac{\beta}{2}$. Using this, the Exterior angle theorem, $\lvert PM\rvert = 14$ and, as suggested in sirous' answer, letting $Q$ be the midpoint of $MP$, then since $MP$ is the diameter of the circumcircle of $\triangle DPM$, we get
$$\lvert DQ\rvert = \lvert QP\rvert = \frac{14}{2} = 7, \;\; \measuredangle QDP = \measuredangle QPD = \frac{\beta}{2} \;\to\; \measuredangle DQC = \beta$$
Also, there's
$$\measuredangle CDQ = 90^{\circ} - \measuredangle CDM - \measuredangle QDP = 90^{\circ} - \left(90^{\circ} - \frac{3\beta}{2}\right) - \frac{\beta}{2} = \beta$$
Since $\measuredangle DQC = \measuredangle CDQ = \beta$, then $\triangle CDQ$ is isosceles and, thus,
$$\lvert CQ \rvert = \lvert CD \rvert = 4 \;\to\; \lvert CP\rvert = \lvert CQ\rvert + \lvert QP\rvert = 4 + 7 = 11$$

You've made a good attempt, but I'm unsure of how to continue with it. Instead, here's a somewhat different approach. Let
$$\measuredangle DAC = \beta \;\to\; \measuredangle DCA = 2\beta \;\to\; \measuredangle CDM = 90^{\circ} - \frac{3\beta}{2} \;\to\; \measuredangle DMC = 90^{\circ} - \frac{\beta}{2}$$
As you've determined, $\measuredangle PDM = 90^{\circ}$, and using $\lvert PM\rvert = 14$, we get
$$\measuredangle DPM = \frac{\beta}{2} \;\to\; \lvert DM \rvert = 14\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)$$
Using the Law of sines with $\triangle CDM$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert DM\rvert}{\sin(2\beta)} & = \frac{\lvert DC\rvert}{\sin\left(90^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2}\right)} \\
\frac{14\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}{\sin(2\beta)} & = \frac{4}{\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)} \\
7\left(2\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\right) & = 4(2\sin\beta\cos\beta) \\
7\sin\beta & = 8\sin\beta\cos\beta \\
\cos\beta & = \frac{7}{8}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Using the above result, the Law of sines with $\triangle CDM$ again, the Triple-angle formulae of $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3\theta - 3\cos\theta$, and the Double-angle formulae of $\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2\theta - 1 \;\to\; 2\cos^2\theta = \cos(2\theta) + 1$, gives that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert MC\rvert}{\sin\left(90^{\circ}-\frac{3\beta}{2}\right)} & = \frac{\lvert DC\rvert}{\sin\left(90^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2}\right)} \\
\frac{\lvert MC\rvert}{\cos\left(\frac{3\beta}{2}\right)} & = \frac{4}{\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)} \\
\lvert MC\rvert & = \frac{4\cos\left(\frac{3\beta}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)} \\
& = \frac{4\left(4\cos^3\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)-3\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)} \\
& = 16\cos^2\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right) - 12 \\
& = 8(1 + \cos\beta) - 12 \\
& = 8\left(1 + \frac{7}{8}\right) - 12 \\
& = 8\left(\frac{15}{8}\right) - 12 \\
& = 15 - 12 \\
& = 3
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Finally, we get
$$\lvert CP\rvert = \lvert MP\rvert - \lvert MC\rvert = 14 - 3 = 11$$

Very good..thaks my friend

@petaarantes You're welcome. I have just added another answer using a simpler method. Since the approach there may also be considered to be more geometric than mine here, I believe you'll like it better.

I saw. It really was a more elegant solution

@petaarantes I agree it's more elegant. I wish I had realized it before I provided my answer above. Although this answer is longer & less elegant, I believe the site benefits from having multiple approaches given to problems since it helps to show there's usually more than one way to solve a problem. Also, what I've done above may potentially be instructive to some people, including even perhaps helping somebody to solve some other problems.

I completely agree, I think that a greater number of approaches provides a greater scope of knowledge and, as you mentioned, allows the idea to be reused in other issues
